# Car decelerating quickly

Tags: brakes, maintenance, tires, braking

I recently changed my brake pads and did wheel alignment at the official workshop of my car manufacturer.

It was driving just fine but suddenly as I was driving it at one fine point the steering became a little harder and now it takes a little more effort to steer. I thought it was a tyre puncture but the tyres were ok. Also the car decelerates quicker than usual, as I take the foot off the accelerator. My tyres seem to be fine - pressure's good.

To recap here are the symptoms:
1. Steering is harder. EPS works but is harder.
2. Car decelerates quicker than usual. At high speeds you can feel a small deceleration as you take the foot off the accelerator.

I think these might be the reasons:
1.Something wrong with my steering system or
2.My brakes are not releasing fully or
3.Something wrong with the fuel filter/ air filter (but does it affect the steering?)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like something is binding or dragging. If you've recently changed the brakes, that would be my first suspect.

Does the steering pull to either side? If so, does it always do so, or only under braking, which would suggest one side binding?

**Carefully** bring the back of your hand to each wheel after a drive - does it feel hot? Is the heat concentrated in the hub or around the brake caliper?

How old is the vehicle? If it's more than 8-10 years old, have the brake flexi hoses ever been changed? These can begin to perish with time, and swell, causing the brakes to bind on as the fluid can't escape back to the master cylinder.

If you jack the front of the car up (in neutral if it is a front or four wheel drive), can you spin the front wheels freely, or do they feel like they are binding?

While it's jacked up, check the steering - it should spin freely from lock to lock, even without the engine on.